# $S = \{\lfloor n^{c} \rfloor : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Show that $d(S) = 0$, if $c > 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We let $S = \{\lfloor n^{c} \rfloor : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. And we need to show that $d(S) = 0$, if $c > 1$. According to the definition of natural density, we have that $$d(S) = \lim_{N \to\infty } \frac{|S \cap [1,N]|}{N}$$ which is equal to $$\lim_{N \to\infty} \frac{|\lfloor n^c \rfloor \cap [1,N] |}{N}$$ But I'm not sure how to go from here to actually show that $d(S) = 0$.
 I'm thinking that maybe we need to show that the denominator outgrows the numerator. Could anyone help me please? Thanks!

Comment: You may want to try to bound the $n$ in the numerator.

Comment: @DavidMoews Yes $c > 1$. I've edited both the content and title to add this condition. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: @DavidMoews I feel like there is no bound for $n$, since according to the definition of this set, $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: True, $n\in\mathbf{N}$, but if $n$ is so big that $n^c>N+1$, it makes no difference to the size of the set in the numerator.

Comment: @DavidMoews Ah I see what you mean. But then when $n$ is large enough, would the numerator be $|[1.N]|$, which is just $N$? But wouldn't this make the limit go to 1?

Comment: No, because the set in the numerator only includes numbers which can be expressed as $\lfloor n^c \rfloor$, for some $n$.

Comment: @DavidMoews So when $n$ is large enough, the numerator is always less than denominator? Since some number cannot be expressed in that way

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.  You need to make a quantitative bound though.